# Creating a function that checks whether input is an integer (in the mathematical sense)

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am creating an alternative function of `IntegerQ[]` function. Now I don't want any output. I just want my function to check whether this is integer or not. I'm gonna use it in another code. My code looks like;

```
IntQ[n_] := Block[{}, GP = 0;
  {j = 0;
   If[n >= 0,
        For[i = n, i > 0, i--, j++],
        For[i = (-n), i > 0, i--, j++]]};
  {If[j == n, True, False]};
  ]
```

It is not working. I just want to know where is the problem, why the problem is causing and how to solve it?
Generally `IntegerQ[6]` would return True as an output and in other function it wouldn't return anything but we can use that value actually. So that's where my problem is.

Comment: May you share why `IntegerQ` is not sufficient for your problem. Might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Well I was asked to create a code without using built-in functions (except for the loops or block codes). In my code I needed to use the `IntegerQ[]` which is not in the condition. That's why was trying to create an alternate.

Comment: @Edmund `IntegerQ` tests only whether the `Head` of the expression equals  `Integer`. There are other undocumented functions though that attempt to check an arbitrary number (e.g. finite precision numbers) for being integers, e.g. ``RandomProcesses`TemporalDataDump`iIntegerQ``.

Comment: The immediate issue as to why no output: it is suppressed by the final semicolon.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `IntegerQ` actually checks if something is internally held as an integer (I think). For example, this returns `False`: ``IntegerQ@Integer[f]``.

Answer (score 2):

This one follows the idea of your implementation and it seems to work:

```
IntQ[n_] := Block[{i},
  i = Abs[N[n]];
  While[Positive[i], i--];
  i == 0.
  ]
```

Testing against the undocumented function `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataDump`iIntegerQ ``:

```
test = {-11.1, -1, -2., -0., 0, 1., 1, 1.5, 1, 11., 11.5, E, Pi};
IntQ /@ test == RandomProcesses`TemporalDataDump`iIntegerQ /@ test
```

> True

One reason why your function did not return anything is the final semicolon `;`. Moreover, the use of braces `{}` for structuring your code is somewhat odd: Braces in *Mathematica* are used to define lists. Use parenthesis `()` for code structuring if necessary.

Also, your code cannot compute the correct result for negativ `n`, because at the end of your function, `j` will be always non-negative, so it cannot equal `n` if the latter is negative.

Other possible variants are

```
IntQ2[n_] := N[Round[N[n]]] == N[n]
IntQ3[n_] := N[Round[N[n]]] === N[n]
```

Please see the details of `Equal` (`==`) and `SameQ` (`===`) for understanding that these two tests are preformed with different tolerances.

Comment: `Sign[n] n` is just `Abs[n]`, of course. ;)

Comment: Ha, ha. Good point @J.M.!

Answer (score 2):

You can define it recursively, without any loops:

```
intQ[0] := True
intQ[n_] := intQ[n - 1] /; n >= 1
intQ[n_] := intQ[n + 1] /; n <= -1
intQ[_] := False
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your code, try with those modifications

```
IntQ[n_] := Block[{},
j = 0;
If[n >= 0, For[i = n, i > 0, i--, j++], 
For[i = (-n), i > 0, i--, j++]];
If[j == Abs[n], True, False]]
```

Comment: Statements of the form `If[cond,True,False]` can usually be replaced by `cond`, or `TrueQ@cond`, if you're worried about the condition being neither `True` nor `False`.